# Change color table when checkbox ticked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AdminLTE template ( Bootstrap ), and i want to change the color of the tr when my checkbox is ticked

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" aria-describedby="example1_info">
                <thead>
                  <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 295px;">
                      ID
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 295px;">
                      ID
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 430px;">
                      Sujet
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 295px;">
                      Nom du client
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 384px;">
                      Département
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 250px;">
                      Status
                    </th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="example1" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 183px;">
                      Derniére reponse
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      ID
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      ID
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      Sujet
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      Client
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      Département
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      Statut
                    </th>
                    <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">
                      Derniere reponse
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      12
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Pb SQL
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-success">
                        SQL
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-success">
                        Ouvert
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      30/09/2014 à 12h24
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      18
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Pb FTP
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-danger">
                        Technique
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-success">
                        Ouvert
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      30/09/2014 à 12h21
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      19
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Quels sont vos DNS ?
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-danger">
                        Technique
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-warning">
                        Reponse client
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      30/09/2014 à 10h13
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      22
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Facture #123456789
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-info">
                        Commercial
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-danger">
                        En attente Tech Niveau II
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      30/09/2014 à 07h34
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                  <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      123
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Paiement reçu ?
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-info">
                        Commercial
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-primary">
                        En attente paiement
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      29/09/2014 à 23h45
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      90
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Pb renouvellement
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-info">
                        Commercial
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-warning">
                        Reponse client
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      29/09/2014 à 21h13
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      193
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Un gay dans l'equipe ?
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-default">
                        Pour Nico
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-warning">
                        Reponse client
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      29/09/2014 à 15h14
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      3045
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Detail offre pro
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-primary">
                        Pré-vente
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-warning">
                        Reponse client
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      29/09/2014 à 13h37
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      4567
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Quel modes de paiement autorisez vous ?
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-info">
                        Commercial
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-primary">
                        Attente serivce commercial
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      29/09/2014 à 10h54
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="even">
                    <td class=" ">
                      <div class="checkbox"> <label> <input type="checkbox" /></label></div>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" sorting_1">
                      6789
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Paiement non abouti
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      Relou
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-danger">
                        Technique
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      <small class="label label-warning">
                        Reponse client
                      </small>
                    </td>
                    <td class=" ">
                      29/09/2014 à 00h01
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

I want to use JS but i don't know how to do :(

Tried this :

```
    $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var $chk = $(this);
  var isChecked = $chk.prop('checked');
  if (isChecked) {
    $chk.parent().addClass("info");
  }
  else {
    $chk.parent().removeClass("info");
  }
});
```

But doesn't work..

I really ned help :(

Thanks a lot ! ( I'm sorry if my english is bad, i am French :))) )

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the parent element which is a label, not the tr. Use `closest` to find the tr that the checkbox is in.

```
$("table tbody").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("info", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: The problem is than AdminLTE edit my div..
<div class="checkbox"> <label class=""> <div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins></div></label></div>

Comment: Why do you keep posting this in everyone's answer? It is an unreadable comment that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ew0va6dx/)

here you are giving the class `.info` for the `label` which is parent of `<input>`

```
$chk.parent().addClass("info");
```

you need to find the exact parent `<tr>` to add class

```
$chk.parents('tr').addClass("info");
```

Comment: Hopefully the page does not have nested tables.

Comment: Admin LTE edit my div..
<div class="checkbox"> <label class=""> <div class="icheckbox_minimal" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" style="position: relative;"><input type="checkbox" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins></div></label></div>